# Bootstrap 3 Navbar in Joomla 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, joomla, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, joomla3.0

I'm trying to create a Bootstrap 3 template in Joomla 3. My main navigation module is called "nav", so I place it on the page with the snippet:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="none" />
```

This creates a ul with the class "nav menu". I need this to be "nav navbar-nav" instead because of the way Bootstrap 3's navbar is set up. How would you go about doing this? Is there a way to do it without Javascript? Here's what I've got so far:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        Menu
    </button>
</div> <!-- navbar-header -->

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
    <jdoc:include type="modules" name="nav" style="none" />
</div> <!-- navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Joomla backend, go to the Menu module, click on the "Advanced" tab and you will see a field called "Module Class Suffix".

In there, add the following:

```
 navbar-nav
```

Note that there is a space before it

Answer (score 0):

The quick solution to this is a module that you can customize as well.

http://thegrue.org/responsive-menu-module-joomla/

Download from above link. It offers responsive menu. You just need to define a module position in your template and assign module there.